# Performance gain using anonymous functions?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm processing 300k huge files and see a major performance issue.

The problem is with the number of checks that are being performed.

We have lots of functions and are planning to turn them into anonymous functions.

I want to know if there is any performance gain to be had when using anonymous functions.

Comment: What function? For checking what?

Comment: 300 kilobytes isn't that huge. Also please specify your problem more clearly with specific examples and details of your code that you want to optimize.

Comment: You do know that function definitions with lambda can only have a single expression right?  Unless you have a lot of one-line functions that are only returning a value, it is unlikely that you will be able to convert them to lambdas.  Even if you can I would expect the performance difference to be negligible.

Comment: Why are you planning on turning them into anonymous functions?

Comment: very relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: do you mean huge files of size 300KB, or 300,000 huge files?  just sayin'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question itself is easily answered, **no** there is no performance gain in using anonymous functions in Python. There is a good chance you are actually making it slower.

A simple `timeit` tests on trivial functions show that there is no real difference between the two. We take these two functions

```
def test(message):
    return message + message

testanon = lambda message: message + message
```

and then use the `timeit` module to test their execution speed:

```
>>> timeit.repeat("test('test')", setup="from __main__ import test")
[0.16360807418823242, 0.1602180004119873, 0.15763211250305176]
>>> timeit.repeat("testanon('test')", setup="from __main__ import testanon")
[0.15949010848999023, 0.15913081169128418, 0.17438983917236328]
```

As is visible, there is no real big performance increase worth actually considering, your performance problem most likely lies somewhere else.